# Hide return value from a Spring MVC controller in SpringFox 2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, documentation-generation, springfox

I have an async Spring MVC controller that returns `Future`. SpringFox 2 renders it as this:

[image]

How do I remove it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work with types.
So, let's suppose that this is the controller method:

```
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO>> getDTO() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseDTO());
}
```

Adding just the configuration:

```
.genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class, CompletableFuture.class)
.directModelSubstitute(CompletableFuture.class, java.lang.Void.class)
```

it will not work. The method needs to be modified to:

```
public CompletableFuture getDTO() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseDTO());
}
```

Then the CompletableFuture definition will disappear from OpenAPI specs.

Found a better approach. I'm using springfox version 2.8.0. If you have a look at their docs ([RTFM](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)) you can have type classes resolved to POJO using a type adapter. An example for this configuration is like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("base package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
            .alternateTypeRules(

 newRule(typeResolver.resolve(CompletableFuture.class,
                            typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
                            typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .pathMapping("/");
}
```

And the controller method can be defined with types:

```
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO>> getDTO() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseDTO());
}
```

Comment: You can try to add `.directModelSubstitute(Future.class, java.lang.Void.class)`. I did not tested with Future. Oh, I thought it's a question :). So, it's working with Futures also.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the issue by adding the following method call to SprinfFox's `Docket`:

```
.genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class, CompletableFuture.class)
```

Hope it will help someone.